# how to remove an item in the list with a condition ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-list-header>
 <span ion-text bold color="primary"> My Application</span>
 </ion-list-header>
 <div *ngIf="userStatus!='Registered' " >
 <ion-item *ngFor="let type of options" (click)="close(type.name)">
 {{type.name}}
  </ion-item>
  </div>
  </ion-list>
```

**This is my array**

```
public options  = 
  [
    {name : 'RegisterMe'},
     {name : 'MY CLINICS'},
  ];
```

***This is my html element***
    I am using ***ngFor="let type of options"** to loop my array. And using data binding to display list `{{type.name}}`
    I want to hide only  **RegisterMe option** in my list with a condition "this.userStatus="registered""
 Hence i am using this condition `ngIf="userStatus!='Registered' "`       BY doing this it is hiding my entire list.

How to achieve this.
    Kindly Help me on this.

Comment: Please provide your template/markup.

Comment: Perfect use case for a Pipe.

Comment: How to use pipes for this query akash. Please help me

Comment: i have edited my post with HTML template @christian

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [pipe](https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-globally-available-custom-pipe-in-angular-2), as mentioned in the comments. Or do some hack like this in the template

```
<div *ngFor="let type of options">
  <ion-item *ngIf="type.name!='RegisterMe'" (click)="close(type.name)">
    {{type.name}}
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

but this is not the best solution, because you are adding an unnecessary div to your markup.